# Viewing <div> using "slideToggle" [ jQuery ]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My code

```
 $('.viewreplycommentbutton').click(function() {
 $(this).next('.reply').slideToggle(200);
 });
```

I have three `<div>`s with the class `.reply` and when i click on a button with a link (which has the class `.viewreplycommentbutton`) it will show only one of those three `<div>`

i want to view all of these when i click on the button (which is a link with the class `.viewreplycommentbutton`)
but without removing `$(this)` from the jQuery code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.next()` returns next immediate sibling element. Use `.nextAll()` to get next all siblings:

```
$('.viewreplycommentbutton').click(function() {
   $(this).nextAll('.reply').slideToggle(200);
});
```